# Proper arguments to ListPlot?

Tags: plotting

```
Eqn1 = -C  f'''''[x] + f'''[x] + f[x]  f''[x] - f'[x]  f'[x] + r^2 + λ  T[x] == 0   

Eqn2 = 
  T''[x] + p1 f[x] T'[x] + 
    p2/(3 (1 - tw)) (12 (tw + (1 - tw) T[x] ) + tw)^2 (1 - tw) T'[x] T'[x] +  
    4 ((1 - tw) T[x] + tw)^3 (1 - tw) T''[x] == 0

BC1 = f[0] == 0
BC2 = f'[0] == 1
BC3 = f'[3] == r
BC4 = f''[3] == 0
BC5 = f'''[3] == 0
BC6 = T'[0] == -B (1 - T[0])
BC7 = T[3] == 0

param4 = {p1 -> 10, B -> 10, tw -> 1.5, p2 -> 0.5, 
  C -> 1, r -> 1}

y4[λ_] := Module[{r1},
   Sol4 = 
    NDSolve[{Eqn1, Eqn2, BC1, BC2, BC3, BC4, BC5, BC6, BC7} /. 
      param4, {f, T}, {x, 0, 3}, 
     Method -> {"Shooting", 
       "StartingInitialConditions" -> {f[0] == 0, f'[0] == 1, 
         f''[0] == 1, f'''[0] == 0, f''''[0] == 1, T[0] == 0, 
         T'[0] == -10}}];
   r1 = -f''[x] /. Sol4 /. x -> 0;
   r1];

data = Table[{λ, y4[λ]}, {λ, 0.0, 1, 0.1}];

{{0., {1.88873*10^-15}}, {0.1, {0.0269271}}, {0.2, {0.0534832}}, \
{0.3, {0.0796794}}, {0.4, {0.105526}}, {0.5, {0.131035}}, {0.6, \
{0.156213}}, {0.7, {0.181072}}, {0.8, {0.20562}}, {0.9, {0.229864}}, \
{1., {0.253815}}}
```

What I did wrong overhere?

```
ListPlot[data, Joined -> True, Mesh -> True, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {{"y(λ)", None}, {λ, 
    "y[λ] vs. λ"}}]
```

[image]

Comment: When I try to run your code, NDSolve spits out a number of error messages.  Do you get these error messages?

Comment: @djp sorry there was typo. Now try again. thanks

Comment: I still can't get y4[] to produce any output for any value of lambda.  Can you?

Comment: @djp yes I do. please see the above data.

Comment: Your `data` has an incompatible format for `ListPlot`. Try e.g. `Flatten/@data`.

Comment: @Yves Klett it worked now. Thx. Should I delete the post or its okay?

Comment: I suggest you should edit the question so that it is useful to other people --- i.e. the problem is nothing to do with NDSolve, but the proper arguments to ListPlot.  Then I think you should post an answer and accept it!

Comment: Glad it helped! I voted to close, but that is nothing personal...  let's see what the community decides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data needs to be in the form `{{x1, y1}, ..., {xn, yn}}`.

```
rawData = 
  {{0., {1.88873*10^-15}}, {0.1, {0.0269271}}, {0.2, {0.0534832}}, {0.3, {0.0796794}}, 
   {0.4, {0.105526}}, {0.5, {0.131035}}, {0.6, {0.156213}}, {0.7, {0.181072}}, 
   {0.8, {0.20562}}, {0.9, {0.229864}}, {1., {0.253815}}};
data = rawData /. {m_, {n_}} :> {m, n}
ListPlot[data, 
  Joined -> True, Mesh -> True, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {{"y(λ)", None}, {λ, "y[λ] vs. λ"}}]
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Yves Klett. The `data` has an incompatible format for `ListPlot`.
In such case we should use `Flatten/@data`.